# Identifying the unhealthy instance id from target group

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I need help in identifying the unhealthy host from a cluster of 6 ec2's under Target group.

1. Right now I have a CloudWatch alarm which triggers whenever there is an unhealthy host but doesn't show which is unhealthy. I am slightly aware that I can use a SNS topic to trigger lambda, but need help from our community here.
2. Is there a way I can run a command on that particular unhealthy instance? or at least reboot it via EC2 actions?

I couldnt extract instance id from cloudwatch ELB metrics to play around.

maybe a different sns topic to run command via systems manager ?
Please give me a detailed answer as I am still learning AWS. :)

Comment: Both the approaches are correct. Triggering Lambda from SNS which will restart the EC2 and/or triggering SSM to run a document to make it healthy through some custom script.
You should try both the approaches and post the questions if you get any errors.

Comment: @saurabh14292 Thank you for the speedy response, The problem I am facing is I couldn't figure out which instance is unhealthy. Is there a way I know which is unhealthy on the CloudWatch graph ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this AWS blog for this exact specific use case.

[Identifying unhealthy targets of Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/identifying-unhealthy-targets-of-elastic-load-balancer/)